# ASP.NET 2.0 : Best Practice for writing Error Page

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, global-asax

In asp.net 2.0 web site, what is the best way of writing Error page. I have seen following section at following location:

Web.Config

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Pages/Common/DefaultRedirectErrorPage.aspx">
```

Global.asax

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
}
```

I am not getting how to use both of them in best way for Error handling.

Please guide me best approach.

Comment: What is you environment? IIS7 or IIS6? .net2.0 or 3.5?

Comment: I am using IIS 6 , .NET 3.5. 

Does it make diffence?

Comment: Error http modules are easier with IIS7, but you can get great functionality with IIS6 , so don't worry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my global asax i always check to see what type of http error it is...

then transfer to the correct error page specified in web.config
I like to handle the usual suspects, 404 ( lost page ) and 500 ( server error )

some background on http status code is importaint to know why they are handled:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

my web.config look something like this

```
<customErrors mode="On"  defaultRedirect="~/error.aspx"  >
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/lost.aspx"  />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/error.aspx"  />
</customErrors>
```

my lost page has logic in it to attempt to find a link to the page that they might have been looking for, as well as some other formatting.

my error page is a bit different, showing some error messages ,

so i handle both differently.

depending if you have secured areas of your site you might want handle the 401/403 ?

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = Context;


    var error = context.Server.GetLastError() as HttpException;
    var statusCode = error.GetHttpCode().ToString();

    // we can still use the web.config custom errors information to
    // decide whether to redirect
    var config = (CustomErrorsSection)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/customErrors");
    if (config.Mode == CustomErrorsMode.On ||
        (config.Mode == CustomErrorsMode.RemoteOnly && context.Request.Url.Host != "localhost"))
    {
        // set the response status code
        context.Response.StatusCode = error.GetHttpCode();

        // Server.Transfer to correct ASPX file for error
        if (config.Errors[statusCode] != null)
        {

            HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer(config.Errors[statusCode].Redirect);
        }
        else
            HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer(config.DefaultRedirect);
    }
}
```

the reason i server transfer is so search engines don't get confused, and to keep my webmaster logs meaningful... if you redirect you return a http status 302 which tell the browser to go to the page redirected to... then this next page returns a status code 200 ( ok ).

302 --> 200 , or even 302 --> 404 has different meaning that just a 404...

then on say my 404 error page i make sure i set the status code of the http error:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Status = "404 Lost";
    Response.StatusCode = 404;

}
```

This article was helpful to me, I knew what I wanted to do but I like how this code looked at the web.config settings... http://helephant.com/2009/02/improving-the-way-aspnet-handles-404-requests/

> **Return the right status code**
>
> By default the page handling a 404
>   error page doesn’t return a 404 status
>   code to the browser. It displays the
>   error message that you provided to the
>   user but doesn’t have any extra
>   information to flag the page as an
>   error page.
>
> This is called a soft 404. Soft 404
>   pages aren’t as good as ones that
>   return the 404 status code because
>   returning the 404 status code lets
>   anything accessing your file that the
>   page is an error page rather than a
>   real page of you site. This is mostly
>   useful for search engines because then
>   they know they should remove dead
>   pages from their index so users won’t
>   follow dead links into your site from
>   results pages.
>
> Pages that return 404 status codes are
>   also useful for error detection
>   because they’ll be recorded in your
>   server logs so if you have unexpected
>   404 errors, they’ll be easy to find.
>   Here’s an example of the 404 error
>   report in Google Webmaster tools:

**EDITS**

> Is it require to write
>   server.clearerror() in global.asax?
>   What does it impact

- No, You can do it on you error pages,
  not sure the impact? if you do a
  transfer non, if you redirect, there
  might be the possibility another
  error happened between the requests?
  I don't know

> Why in web.config we should write error.aspx 
>   twice one with status code 500 and another is 
>   defaultredirect

- I use 2 because a lost page should
  show/and do different things than a
  server error. the error page shows
  the user there was an error that we
  could not recover from... and its
  probably our fault.  I leave a
  default redirect for any of the other
  error codes as well. 403,401,  400 (
  they are more rare, but should be
  handled )

> Can you also tell me the code of error.aspx and lost.aspx.

- this depends on the type of website
  you have. you get the error the same
  way, but what you do with it is up to
  you. on my lost page i search for
  some content the user might have been
  looking for. the error pages i log
  the error and so a user friendly oops
  page... you will need to figure out
  what is needed.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for nice information. Can you also tell me that what is the advantage of writing Response.Status = "404 Lost";    Response.StatusCode = 404; 

and second Should we write two redirect pages in web.config?

Comment: expanded a little...  look at some of the resources i added.

Comment: Thanks, Now i think i got that why server.transfer required in application_error page, so that getlasterror will accessible at error.aspx/lost.aspx. If we doesn't write explicitly server.transfer, then also error page will show but by using response.redirect which cannot access last error. Here i would like to know three points (1) Is it require to write server.clearerror() in global.asax? What does it impact (2) Why in web.config we should write error.aspx twice one with status code 500 and another is defaultredirect (3) Can you also tell me the code of error.aspx and lost.aspx.

Comment: No, You can get the error with response redirect, but you return a 302 to the client, the 302 tells the cleint to then go to the error page... its and extra step that is not as good as a server tranfer that only returns the 1 time... ( read the article i linked to...)

Comment: Hi sir, I am very thankfull to you for guiding me in such a nice way. As much i read your reply my curiosity increase for more. I have parallel read microsoft msdn. There i found following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417.aspx
 Can you please explain me (1) Compare your solution with Microsoft
(2) As per i learn i found your application error good but I found few good thing at microsoft link ?
(3) Can you please guide me to use it in best way?

Comment: Hi sir, Had you gone with the link i send you. What do you think now

Answer (score 3):

BigBlondeViking's response worked great for me except that I found it did not process 403's (which ASP generates when you try to directly access the /Scripts/ or /Content/ directories.)  It appears that this is not propegated as an exception and thus not trappable in the Application_Error handling.  (this was identified as a "security vulnerability" by an external firm - don't get me started on that!)

```
protected void Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Context.Items.Contains("HasHandledAnError")) // have we alread processed?
    {
        if (Response.StatusCode > 400 &&  // any error
            Response.StatusCode != 401)   // raised when login is required
        {
            Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();    // this is null if an ASP error
            if (exception == null)
            {
                exception = new HttpException((int)Response.StatusCode, HttpWorkerRequest.GetStatusDescription(Response.StatusCode));
            }
            HandleRequestError(exception); // code shared with Application_Error
        }
    }
}
```

I also made a minor change in my common Error Handling.  As we are using ASP.NET MVC, I wanted to explicitly call into a controller, as well as pass the exception object.  This allowed me to access the exception itself so that I can log / send detailed e-mail depending on the code;

```
public ActionResult ServerError(Exception exception)
{
    HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;
    if(httpException != null)
    {
        switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
        {
            case 403:
            case 404:
                Response.StatusCode = 404;
                break;
        }
        // no email...
        return View("HttpError", httpException);
    }
    SendExceptionMail(exception);
    Response.StatusCode = 500;
    return View("ServerError", exception);
}
```

In order to pass the exception OBJECT (not just the message and code) I explicitly invoked the controller:

```
protected void HandleRequestError(Exception exception)
{
    if (Context.Items.Contains("HasHandledAnError"))
    {
        // already processed
        return;
    }
    // mark as processed.
    this.Context.Items.Add("HasHandledAnError", true);

    CustomErrorsSection customErrorsSection = WebConfigurationManager.GetWebApplicationSection("system.web/customErrors") as CustomErrorsSection;

    // Do not show the custom errors if
    // a) CustomErrors mode == "off" or not set.
    // b) Mode == RemoteOnly and we are on our local development machine.
    if (customErrorsSection == null || !Context.IsCustomErrorEnabled ||
        (customErrorsSection.Mode == CustomErrorsMode.RemoteOnly && Request.IsLocal))
    {
        return;
    }

    int httpStatusCode = 500;   // by default.
    HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;
    if (httpException != null)
    {
        httpStatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
    }

    string viewPath = customErrorsSection.DefaultRedirect;
    if (customErrorsSection.Errors != null)
    {
        CustomError customError = customErrorsSection.Errors[((int)httpStatusCode).ToString()];
        if (customError != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(customError.Redirect))
        {
            viewPath = customError.Redirect;
        }
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewPath))
    {
        return;
    }

    Response.Clear();
    Server.ClearError();

    var httpContextMock = new HttpContextWrapper(Context);
    httpContextMock.RewritePath(viewPath);
    RouteData routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(httpContextMock);
    if (routeData == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("Did not find custom view with the name '{0}'", viewPath));
    }
    string controllerName = routeData.Values["controller"] as string;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerName))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("No Controller was found for route '{0}'", viewPath));
    }
    routeData.Values["exception"] = exception;

    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext(httpContextMock, routeData);
    IControllerFactory factory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
    IController errorsController = factory.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
    errorsController.Execute(requestContext);
}
```