# .Net defaultRedirect to locale-specific error page

Tags: .net, asp.net, redirect, localization, globalization

I have an ASP.Net webforms application that uses the .Net globalization features to deliver .aspx pages in different locales.  I have custom errors defined as

```
 <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="Error.htm">
```

I prefer using a non-.Net page for the defaultRedirect to prevent the potential for infinite loops, in case the error page itself generates an error, so I have targeted a static .htm page.  However, I would like to render that page in the locale that the user originally requested, where the locale is determined from a querystring.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

I have considered these options, but I am interested in other options:

- Redirect to some other app/domain that can run server-side logic to redirect to or render a locale-specific response (seems like overkill)
- Use client-side code (JavaScript) to render locale-specific content (doesn't work for JavaScript-disabled browsers, though, and I would like it to work for these users too)
- Make the static error page display text in multiple languages--show all language text on one page (I prefer to only show text in one locale, though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have concluded that the best practice is to generally follow the method outlined in the answer to the following question, only transfer to a .htm page instead of an .aspx page:

[ASP.NET 2.0 : Best Practice for writing Error Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227632/asp-net-2-0-best-practice-for-writing-error-page)

Answer (score 1):

If your project file structure has language specific folders, one solution is to create a **web.config** with just the `<customErrors />` section specified in each language folder

Example Project Structure

- App_Code
- ...
- en-us

  - ...
  - web.config
- en-gb

  - ...
  - web.config
- zh-cn

  - ...
  - web.config
- ...
- Default.aspx
- web.config

Answer (score 0):

if you can create a dynamic page for error information, taking care about the localization and other things, i think that is the best way.

You can handle errors on **global.asax** our developing your own **httpmodule** (both ways are valid) you can manage the application errors by a great and dynamic way, taking control of all process.

including determine current laguage to decide about a possible redirect, or for example display different messages about different kind of errors.

in my opinion i start resolving a problem with a solution  that givesme flexibility to deside how can i handle on different cases.